# When asked to select raster for elevation (in 3D configuration/QGIS) will be the DEM raster as downloaded or DEM raster re projected?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dem, 3d-map

Do you need to re-project Aster GDEM data from USGS Explorer into a metric coordinate system in order to be able to view a map in 3d mode in QGIS?
 Or you just use the file input as it is downloaded from USGS?

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: I have tried , the 3d view works with both inputs and the results are not very different so I wanted to be sure which one is the good one.

Comment: Then why don't you put this as your question instead of asking something very unspecific and opinionbased?

Comment: Because I am just learning QGIS and I am not sure about it.  I just wanted a second opinion . If you cannot help why do you need to be rude?

Comment: GIS.SE is for help with specific problems. Opinion-based questions are rather frowned upon.

Comment: I didn't know that..It was listed on QGIS support and I assumed that will be anything related with specific/ opinion based questions.

Comment: The idea is to answer questions, not to discuss them. Since it is rather hard to get a final answer on an opinion-based question, those are frowned upon.